# Fixing gnutls which is prone to CVE-2018-16868

Tags: freebsd, pycurl, gnutls

I am having a FreeBSD server and using pycurl as a library for doing the curl.

Since it has gnutls too which is prone to CVE-2018-16868(Bleichenbacher type side-channel based padding attack), I am searching for a fix that can help in avoiding this issue.

I have surfed the internet but didn't get any information regarding this issue from pycurl perspective.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about operating systems and their software should be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FreeBSD port was updated to 3.6.5 on 19 Dec 2018 09:32:32

According to https://gitlab.com/gnutls/gnutls/blob/master/NEWS 3.6.5 implements the necessary patches against the attacks from that CVE.

See also https://gitlab.com/gnutls/gnutls/merge_requests/832 and https://gitlab.com/gnutls/gnutls/issues/630 for the patch and the bugticket.

So just updating your ports should fix the issue